# Finding Controls of the Same Type

Tags: silverlight, controls

Does anybody have a good way of finding ALL the controls within an object that is of the same type?  Here's my scenario, I have a tab control and within each tab control exists a user control (ALL of which match the same base type e.g. MyBaseClassControl).  I want to be able to find that user control WITHOUT having to use the control.FindName("controlName") method, rather I would like to get a handle on the control by type (e.g. base class).  The VisualTreeHelper class seems to do nothing for me as it only returns native Silverlight objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> AllChildren(this DependencyObject root)
{
    var children = root.DirectChildren().ToList();
    return children.Union(children.SelectMany(o => o.AllChildren()));
}

public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> DirectChildren(this DependencyObject parent)
{
    var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        yield return System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
}
```

You could do this:

```
myObj.AllChildren().OfType<MyBaseClassControl>();
```

Comment: Oddly enough this extension method never return my custom base type.  Is the "GetChildren" methods in the VisualTreeHelper recursive?  I forgot to mention that the control I am looking for is contained in a Grid.

Comment: Should work although seriously inefficient.  `Union` needs to track objects are not included more than once in the output which in this case is unecessary, children are placed are placed in a `List<T>` (also unnecessary) and all of this is done recursively which on a deeply nested object tree grows the cost of all of this massively.

Comment: Agreed, if performance becomes the issue this can and should be optimized. For the purpose of the question - e.g. how to find a control by type - this does demonstrate it though.